# Alternatives to Hibernate Search mapping Entities through annotations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, gradle, hibernate-search

As far I know there is no **XML alternatives** to mapping an Entity for **Hibernate Search**. Having a XML configuration for search might not be a good idea though. But in my specific case, I have a gradle multi module Spring project like -

- **common** : *that contains the the common entities and services*
- **crawler**: *this uses the common entities and have its own services*
- **search** : *this also uses the common entities and contains search related services*

This is not a single project rather I generate separate *war* from this like *crawler.war* or *search.war*. So you see I need to use the common entities for all separate module and thus separate generated war. Hence having the Hibernate Search mapping annotations directly in the common entities should not be expected.

Now I want to know is there any way I can infuse the common entities with Hibernate Search annotations when importing them in Search module ?

[Any other project structure related suggestion or advice is much appreciated]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation, you can use the [programmatic mapping API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#hsearch-mapping-programmaticapi).

Basically, in your "search" project, you have to write a class defining the mapping:

```
public class MyAppSearchMappingFactory {
    @Factory
    public SearchMapping getSearchMapping() {
        SearchMapping mapping = new SearchMapping();
        mapping
            .analyzerDef( "en", StandardTokenizerFactory.class )
                .filter( LowerCaseFilterFactory.class )
                .filter( EnglishPorterFilterFactory.class )
            .entity(Address.class).indexed()
                .property("addressId", ElementType.METHOD)
                    .documentId()
                        .name("id")
                .property("street1", ElementType.METHOD)
                    .field()
                        .analyzer("en")
                        .store(Store.YES)
                    .field()
                        .name("address_data")
                        .analyzer("en");
        return mapping;
    }
}
```

And then configure Hibernate Search to use this class as a source for your mappings, as shown below.

- If you use a `.properties` file for Hibernate-related configuration:

  ```
  hibernate.search.model_mapping = com.acme.MyAppSearchMappingFactory
  ```
- If you use a `persistence.xml` file for Hibernate-related configuration:

  ```
  <persistence ...>
      <persistence-unit name="...">
          ...
          <properties>
              <property name="hibernate.search.model_mapping"
                        value="com.acme.MyAppSearchMappingFactory"/>
          </properties>
      </persistence-unit>
  </persistence>
  ```

Comment: thats a wondeful finding. I was not aware of *programmatic mapping API*. upvote for you. let me try this. if it works(hope so) I will accept your answer.